# Arduino SD card adapter

Tags: arduino, usb, sd

У меня есть плата arduino nano.мне из неё нужно сделать устройство которое меряет температуру воды в солнечном коллекторе. Но она имеет объем памяти в 1кб, соответственно телеметрия за 1день в неё не помешается. У меня есть устройство которое позволяет подавать на неё питание не занимая при этом встроенный usb-порт. можно ли каким-то образом подключить к встроенному микро USB флешку чтобы arduino сохраняла информации на неё.

Comment: http://arduino-diy.com/arduino-SD-karta

Comment: По этой ссылке они предлагают использовать доп модуль. А можно ли использовать для этого встроенный порт в ардуино.

Comment: Встроенный USB работает как USB-клиент, а для поддержки флешек нужно чтобы он работал как USB-хост. Для добавления USB-хоста нужен отдельный модуль (со своим USB выходом) - что-то типа такого: http://www.freeduino.ru/arduino/USB-Host-shield.html . Проще взять просто модуль для SD карт.

Comment: Спасибо, очень жалко(

Comment: К Arduino можно подключить SD-карту напрямую, без USB

Comment: Каким образом? У меня Nano.